# Proof that a point is sable in linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes

I'm reading an article leading to the following system
$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{lll}
                y_a'(t) &= &-k_1y_a(t)+k_3y_b(t)y_c(t) \\
                y_b'(t) &= & k_1y_a(t)-k_3y_b(t)y_c(t)-k_2[y_b(t)]^2 \\
                y_c'(t) &= & k_2[y_b(t)]^2
                \end{array} \right. $$
$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{lll}
                y_a'(0) &= &1 \\
                y_b'(0) &= &0 \\
                y_c'(0) &= &0
                \end{array} \right. $$
with $k_1,k_2,k_3 >0$. We can prove that for $t>0$, $y_a(t),y_b(t),y_c(t)\geq0$. And that the critical points are $(0,0,\gamma )$, $\gamma \geq 0$.

To know if $(0,0,\gamma )$ is stable we can first verify that it is the case for the linearised system
$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{lll}
                y_a'(t) &= &-k_1y_a(t)+k_3\gamma y_b(t) \\
                y_b'(t) &= & k_1y_a(t)-k_3\gamma y_b(t) \\
                y_c'(t) &= & 0
                \end{array} \right. $$
The author is saying that it's trivially the case but I don't understand why. I've tried to calculate the eigenvalues to use Lyapunov's theorem, I found that
$$P_A(X) = -X[X^2+X(k_1+k_3) +k_1k_3(1-\gamma )]$$
then I have to discuss $(1-\gamma)\leq 0$, etc.. and can't conclude. Plus the eigenvalue $\lambda_1 =0$ do not verify that $\Re (\lambda_1 )<0$.

> Am I missing something? Should I try to calculate $\exp (tA)$, planning to use Duhamel formula?

Any help will be greatly appreciate.